# Start PHP script before file upload completes

Tags: php, linux, apache

Our Apache/PHP server accepts large-ish file uploads and once it gets the file does some behind the scenes DB calls that can take upwards of 300ms.

Is there a way I can get PHP to do some processing, like the DB calls before the file is fully uploaded? Then once the file is uploaded continue and wrap up?

I know the file is part of the HTTP request body and Apache won't kick off the PHP process until it's complete. However, I'm thinking there may be a way to get Apache to kick off another process at the start of a request or something...

Comment: You can use ajax to start uploading the files as soon as the required information is available. So before the form is submitted. Probably already when they files are selected if you can rely on for example session information as you need to be able to link the files to the form later on.

Comment: The idea is to do both in parallel to save time. The files are actually getting POSTED using a native Mac App, and dozens of them one after another. Each file causes about 300ms of DB calls. If I can do that while the file is uploading it would be ideal.